# What are the diagonals in the matrix called?

Tags: matrices, terminology

How correctly to designate these diagonals? They are highlighted in different colors.

\begin{pmatrix}\color{green}1&\color{orange}2&\color{red}3&\color{blue}4\\
\color{orange}5&\color{red}6&\color{blue}7&\color{green}8\\
\color{red}9&\color{blue}{10}&\color{green}{11}&\color{orange}{12}\\
\color{blue}{13}&\color{green}{14}&\color{orange}{15}&\color{red}{16}\end{pmatrix}

$\color{green}{1, 14, 11, 8}$

$\color{orange}{5, 2, 15, 12}$

$\color{red}{9, 6, 3, 16}$

$\color{blue}{13,10, 7, 4}$ - secondary diagonal

Comment: If you consider the diagonals in the other way I use to call them "Principal Diagonal (1 6 11 16), Upper Diagonal (2 7 12) and Lower Diagonal (5 10 15). So, maybe, you can call them Secondary Upper/Lower etc.

Comment: @lioness99a Great improvement of the question.

Comment: You could call them cycled antidiagonals. Antidiagonal matrix is the name i learned for the matrix with only values in the blue spots and 0 everywhere else.

Comment: @callculus Thanks, LaTeX/MathJax can be a very powerful tool if you know what you're doing!

Answer (score 2):

A cyclic generator matrix ( a generator for the cyclic group of order 4 ):

$$ {\bf C} =\left[\begin{array}{cccc}0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$$

if we multiply to the left of

$${\bf M} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}0&0&0&\color{blue} 4\\0&0&\color{blue}3&0\\0&\color{blue}2&0&0\\\color{blue}1&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$$

It generates ${\bf CM} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}0&0&\color{red}3&0\\0&\color{red}2&0&0\\\color{red}1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&\color{red}4\end{array}\right], {\bf C}^2{\bf M} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}0&\color{orange}2&0&0\\\color{orange}1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&\color{orange}4\\0&0&\color{orange}3&0\end{array}\right]$ , ${\bf C}^3{\bf M} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}\color{green}1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&\color{green}4\\0&0&\color{green}3&0\\0&\color{green}2&0&0\end{array}\right]$

These are the ones you color, therefore we could call it something with cyclic: cyclic diagonals or cyclically generated antidiagonals.